# How can I add css to .after function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $('#btnSoumettre').click(function(){    
      $('.must').each(function( index ) {

            if( !$(this).val() ) {
              $(this).css('border-color','red');
              $(this).after( "*" );           
            }    
        });
   });
});
```

Here is a simple bit of jQuery. What I want to know is how can I add my string and make it red?

Comment: Add a css class `.required { color: red }`  then add a div `$(this).after("<div class='required'>*</div>")`

Comment: But you'd be better off not *adding* it, but having it there already and then showing/hiding based on your validation.  Otherwise your next question will be: how to remove text...

Comment: due to your just adding text, you can put the css rule the line before and it will affect your `*`. That being said, as others have said, it would be better to do it with a class instead.

Comment: To explain why your snippet won't work: `.after()` does not return its parameter, it returns the element it's attached to. In your example, your `.css('color', 'red')` will apply to `$(this)`, not `.after("*")`. Reference: [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) vs [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/). (Read the first paragraph of either link)

Comment: The problem with the div is that my string is going under my input field when i need it on the side of it

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED based on comment:**

You can do the following to activate border when there is no value, and remove it when value is entered.

- Remove .after() since it's unnecessary.
- Add an else to remove border once value is entered.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSoumettre').click(function() {
    $('.must').each(function(index) {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        $(this).next('span').css('display', 'inline');
      } else {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'initial');
        $(this).next('span').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
first <input class="must" value="value1"><span> required</span><br> 
second - no value <input class="must"><span> required</span><br> 
third <input class="must" value="value3"><span> required</span><br> 
fourth no value <input class="must"><span> required</span><br>
<button id="btnSoumettre">validate</button>
```

Comment: this is great you actually made me realize i have no way to remove the red border but i still need my errore message on the right side of the input field.